# Variable argument placement in methods

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented, api-design, language-design

Imagine that we have a base class `number` that has implemented a integer and floats, but not complex numbers and that we would like to extend it to also support complex numbers:

```
;; this is from the number implementation
(defgeneric add ((a number) (b number))
  (:documentation "Adds two numbers together."))

(defmethod number:add ((a my-complex-number) (b my-complex-number))
  ...)

(defmethod number:add ((a my-complex-number) (b number))
  ...)

(defmethod number:add ((b number) (a my-complex-number))
  ...)
```

The body of the two last would be exatly the same and yet they are needed in order to do `(reduce #'add list-of-numbers)` since the `number` implementation doesn't know how to add complex numbers.

It seems to me like some sort of syntax to indicate the (or some) arguments can occur in any order. In CL I'm sure this can be fixed by making a macro that generates all the versions, but this isn't just a CL problem.

Imagine you have a number tower with an `add` method in Java and you extend it with a MyComplexNumber class with the same `add` method. How does noe make sure `floatObject.add(complexObject)` would work?

ComplexNumber know of the Number class hiarchy but not vice versa. Thus by importing ComplexNumber package it would be nice to "infect" the other classes add methods without changing their code.

Is there a language out there that has abstraction to solve this?

Comment: "Multimethods" could be what you are looking for.

Comment: In your specific example, I think you have your class hierarchy upside-down. Making `ComplexNumber` the base class seems to make all the problems go away. One typically expects subclasses to be more specific and the problem in the example seems to come from the fact that you're trying to make a subclass (complex numbers) that are more general than the base class (real numbers).

Comment: Also, since you're asking for examples of languages with a particular feature, I wonder if [programmers.se] would be a better fit for this question?

Comment: @DaveClarke Notice I'm searhing for reduceing my CL example to not implement both of the last two versions since they are practicly identical except the argument order. If it was `4` arguments then we'd have to implement `4!` versions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Its not upside down. Usually you cannot choose the base class of a programming language numeric tower or a library you didn't write. I'll add it to my list of ideas but I think my question is simpler than that. I'm looking for programming language design so CS is perhaps better than PSE in this case.

Comment: @Sylwester OK. Please edit your question to be clear that it's about design: you ask "Is there a language out there that has abstraction to solve this?" so it looks like the answer you want is "Language X can do this."

Comment: I agree with David. That said, parametric types with type bounds can do this for you.